# R: rowsum function changes order of groups after aggregation

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I've got this data frame which has duplicates (same `ID` but different numbers):

```
ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
45 1  0  0  1  0
45 0  1  0  0  1
15 1  0  1  0  0
7  1  0  1  1  0
7  0  1  0  0  0
```

I want to sum the vectors that have the same ID so I've used `rowsum`:

```
m <- rowsum(m, m$ID)
```

However it messes up with the order of the rows showing something like this:

```
ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
15 1  0  1  0  0
45 1  1  0  1  1
 7 1  1  1  1  0
```

Instead of what I want:

```
ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
45 1  1  0  1  1
15 1  0  1  0  0
 7 1  1  1  1  0
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Or in the end do as last step: `m[order(m[,1],decreasing = T),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `reorder = FALSE` in `rowsum`.

---

From `?rowsum`:

```
reorder: if ‘TRUE’, then the result will be in order of
          ‘sort(unique(group))’, if ‘FALSE’, it will be in the order
          that groups were encountered.
```